# Query para quitarle todas las letras para que solo quede con los números de un campo alfanumérico

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Tengo toda la columna alfanumérica y solo quiero quedarme con los numeros:

CodigoVuelo
OF5EFE22
WDWD5562
RGR5VE12
W5A4DS12
.
.
.

Y QUE QUEDE ASI:
CodigoVuelo
522
5562
512
5412
.
.
.

1523 registros

Comment: ¿Nos mostrarías lo que has intentado al momento por favor?

Comment: Si lo quieres conseguir con SQL ayudaría saber qué base de datos estás usando y como decía el otro ocmentario, es importante que muestres qué has intentado hasta el momento para ver mejor cómo podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Ayúdate de REGEXP de mysql

Answer (score 1):

A partir de Mysql v8.0 puedes usar la función [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace), por ejemplo:

```
mysql> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('OF5EFE22 WDWD5562 RGR5VE12 W5A4DS12','[A-Z]','');
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('OF5EFE22 WDWD5562 RGR5VE12 W5A4DS12','[A-Z]','') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 522 5562 512 5412                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Simple, elegante y funcional; solo considera que está funcionalidad depende si el OP usa dicha versión

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo resolverlo mediante una función:

```
CREATE FUNCTION extrae_numeros(txt varchar(255))
RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
  DECLARE l int;
  declare letra char(1);
  DECLARE resultado varchar(255);
  set resultado='';
  set l=CHAR_LENGTH(txt);
  WHILE l>0 DO 
    SET l=l-1;
    SET letra=SUBSTR(txt,l,1);
    IF letra IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') THEN
      SET resultado=CONCAT(letra,resultado);
    END IF;
  END WHILE;  
  RETURN resultado;
END;
```

A la que, llamando así:

```
SELECT extrae_numeros('OF5EFE22 WDWD5562 RGR5VE12 W5A4DS12');
```

Obtendrás:

```
5225562512541
```

Es un código bastante simple, déjame en los comentarios cualquier duda y amplío la respuesta.